# Identity relating to positive elements in a $C^*$-algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra and $a\in A$ with $||a||\leq 1$.

How might one go about showing that, for any continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, we have the identity $af(a^*a)=f(aa^*)a$?

Comment: Can you give some context for this question? I cannot imagine in which sense it should be relevant that the norm of $a$ is bounded by $1$...

Comment: Perhaps it relates to another part of the question I haven't stated, where it is required that $1 - a^*a$ and $1 - aa^*$ have square roots. In any case, I included it as I wasn't sure if it might be relevant to the above question.

Comment: Your $f$ goes from $\mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{C}$ and yet eats arguments from $A$. Can you elaborate? Also: is your $A$ defined over $\mathbb{R}$ or over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Here, $f$ acts on the $C^*$-algebra $A$ via functional calculus.

Comment: @MaikPickl: this is a question about C$^*$-algebras. Functional calculus is a (very) basic tool, and requires no explanation to ask a question.

Comment: @MartinArgerami But I'm still allowed to ask if I don't know, am I?

Comment: @MaikPickl: yes and no. Your question is the analogue of asking "what is the $\int$ symbol?", or "what is a function?" in a calculus question. A C$^*$-algebra is a type of object  (usually of infinite-dimensional), and there is a way to evaluate functions on selfadjoint elements. A proper explanation takes a significant chapter of a textbook.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $f$ a polynomial it is true. I.e. 
$$
a (a^*a)^n = a(a^*a)\cdots(a^*a) = (aa^*)\cdots(aa^*)a = (aa^*)^na.
$$